# How to create a custom designed admob banner

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I've been looking into integrating admob banners into my app as iAD has shit down but as of now the banner just look really ugly and offputting.

I saw in other apps that people were using a custom design for their ad banner that works online with their ui design. See the attached images

The images below all have the google admob play logo icon thing which must mean its admob but I've checked the docs and found no way of re-creating this.

My best thought was to pull the ad data from a URL request and populate a class with that data and when the user clicks on it take them to the AppStore but I am not sure that this is allowed in admob iOS natively.

Anybody got ideas on what to do?

[image: iTranslate App]
[image: Oovo App you can see the custom banner]

Comment: You can design "Native Ads" as part of AdMob. Instead of creating a banner ad, choose native ad

Comment: I'll have a look at that